# Datatable is not working when I populate table using smarty

Tags: jquery, datatables, smarty

My datatable is not working when I populate the table in smarty. Its working fine with hard coded tbody.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {foreach $posts as $post }
            <tr>
                <td>{$post.title}</td>
            <tr>
        {/foreach}
    </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two `<tr>`-element openings in your `foreach`-loop. This produces invalid HTML-content inside the table.

```html
{foreach $posts as $post }
  <tr>
    <td>{$post.title}</td>
  </tr>
{/foreach}
```